# Is the function $h(x,y)=\frac{x^3y^3}{x^4+y^6}$ if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ ; $h(0,0) = 0$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I think it is, because I cannot find a set such that the limit through it  is different from $0$. However, polar coordinates don't simplify the way and I'm not able to bound the function. Any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: 8 minutes were enough to make you understand the post below and to be sure that it needed no correction and that no other later post would surpass it? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is continuous at $(0,0)$. It is enough to consider $x,y>0$. [Because $(|x|,|y|) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to 0$ and $|h(x,y)|=\frac {|x|^{3} |y|^{3}} {|x|^{4}+|y|^{6}}$].  Since $(x^{2}-y^{3})^{2} \geq 0$ we get $x^{4}+y^{6} \geq 2x^{2}y^{3}$ so  $ 0<\frac {x^{3}y^{3}} {x^{4}+y^{6}} \leq\frac {x^{3}y^{3}} {2x^{2}y{3}}=\frac x 2$ and $\frac x 2$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Several absolute values are lacking from your post. Please correct it.

Comment: @Did  I did say in the second sentence that it is enough to consider $x,y >0$.

Comment: Bad idea. To justify that it is, takes more time and more thinking than to add absolute values.

Comment: @Did I don't agree. $h(x,y) \to 0$ iff $|h(x,y)| \to 0$. What is $|h(x,y)|$?

Comment: What? Of course, $|h(x,y)|=\frac{|x|^3|y|^3}{x^4+y^6}$. 1. Not obvious? 2. Your point being?

Answer (score 1):

By $\text{HM}\le\text{GM}$,

$\dfrac{2}{\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{y^6}}\le\sqrt{x^4\cdot y^6}=x^2\cdot y^3\implies\dfrac{x^4y^6}{x^4+y^6}\le\dfrac{x^2\cdot y^3}{2}\implies h(x,y)=\dfrac{x^3y^3}{x^4+y^6}\le\dfrac{x}{2}\to0\text{ as }x\to0$

Hence $h(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0).$